# Bootstrap 5 Horizontal Scroll for Multiple Rows

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, flexbox, bootstrap-5, bootstrap-grid

Container is scrollable only for half of the container. After that scrolling starts to affect navigation panel as well.

CSS:

```
  .horizontal-scrollable {
        overflow-x: auto;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container horizontal-scrollable" style="border: 1px solid lime;">
    <div class="row flex-nowrap"  style="border: 5px solid gold">
        <div class="col" style="border: 1px solid red;">Column</div>
        <div class="col" style="border: 1px solid red;">Column</div>
        <div class="col" style="border: 1px solid red;">Column</div>
            <div class="col" style="border: 1px solid red;">Column</div>
        </div>
    <div class="row flex-nowrap"  style="border: 5px solid gold">
        <div class="col" style="border: 1px solid red;">Column</div>
        <div class="col" style="border: 1px solid red;">Column</div>
        <div class="col" style="border: 1px solid red;">Column</div>
            <div class="col" style="border: 1px solid red;">Column</div>
        </div>
    <div class="row flex-nowrap"  style="border: 5px solid gold">
        <div class="col" style="border: 1px solid red;">Column</div>
        <div class="col" style="border: 1px solid red;">Column</div>
            <div class="col" style="border: 1px solid red;">Column</div>
            <div class="col" style="border: 1px solid red;">Column</div>
        </div>
</div>
```

[Works, thus container is crollable while navigation is still][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vYKUY.png
[Stopped working after some breakpoint, whole page is moving][2]
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IgnTZ.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to make all the row div elements as inline, using `display: inline-block;` property.

For your case, it would be like

```
.horizontal-scrollable > .row > .col{
            display: inline-block;
}
```

Also, try changing the code from Horizontal-scrollable to the the row elements inside that div.

```
  .horizontal-scrollable > .row {
        overflow-x: auto;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }
```

I found the this to be working for me. You can reference this [here.](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-make-horizontal-scrollable-in-a-bootstrap-row/)

Comment: This may work for B3, but not for B5.